# How to get "Guid" variable from http header in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, header, guid

The following line gives an error (cannot convert type "string" to "System.Guid")

```
userId = Request.QueryString["id"];
```

is there any solution to pass Guid variable in http header Get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try {
    userId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"]);
} catch (FormatException e) {
    /*
     * It's possible that the guid is not properly formatted and an
     * exception will be thrown, so handle that here.
     */
}
```